# Returning the first node in a list

Tags: c, list

I'm asked to return the first Node in a list, in a given generic struct, but I'm having trouble to figure out the most efficient way to do so.

Is doing a previous pointer (besides next) is the only way?

```
struct Map_t {
    Map next;
    MapDataElement currentData;
    MapKeyElement currentKey;
};
```

Comment: By first Node you mean the first Node that was added to the list or the last? (because if you are adding to the end, then the first added Node will actually be the last when traversing the list)

Comment: The first one added to the list

Comment: If you are going to implement a typical singly linked list, your should store your's list head somewhere (assuming your list list grows towards the tail). You can also store the tail so you don't have to iterate over the whole list every time you want to delete something from the end.

Comment: How can I store the head in the struct?

Comment: You have a pointer variable somewhere that points to the head of the list(this pointer is not part of the structure itself).

Comment: So how do I do the function getFirst? which is in the structure itself.

Comment: If Itachi's comment didn't help you at all, then I suggest you to read more on how to implement linked lists in C. We could give you an example implementation, but that's not the point.

Comment: Not directly related, but hiding pointer types with typedefs is a bad idea, I suppose you have a `typedef struct Map_t *Map;` somewhere. `struct Map_t *next;` instead `Map next;` would me so much clearer.

Comment: Your question is not very comprehensible. What do you mean by return the first node in the list? The first node in the list is the one pointed to by the head. Why is that difficult to return, and why would you even be asked to return it?!

Answer (score 0):

You provide very little information.

I guess you need something like this:

```
struct List
{
  struct Map_t *head;
  struct Map_t *tail;
};

struct Map_t {
  struct Map_t *next;
  MapDataElement currentData;
  MapKeyElement currentKey;
};

// Initialize list for first use
void InitializeList(struct List *l)
{
  l->head = l->tail = NULL;
}

// add new data/key pair to list
void AddToList(struct List *l, MapDataElement data, MapKeyElement key)
{
  struct Map_t *newnode = malloc(sizeof(*newnode));
  newnode->currentData = data;
  newnode->currentKey = key;
  newnode->next = NULL;

  if (l->head == NULL)
  {
    // special case when list is empty
    l->head = l->tail = newnode;
  }
  else
  {
    // list is non empty
    l->tail->next = newnode;  // append new node to tail
    l->tail = newnode;        // tail becomes newnode
  }
}


int main()
{
  struct List mylist;         // your list
                              // the head of the list is stored permanently
                              // in mylist.head
  InitializeList(&mylist);

  MapDataElement data = ...;  // get data from somewhere
  MapKeyElement key = ...;    // get key from somewhere
  AddToList(&mylist, data, key);
  ...
}
```

As already stated in a comment: the head of the list is stored permanently `mylist.head`.

Disclaimer: this is untested and incomplete code. No error checking is done for brevity.